# HSQLDB not properly recognizing Primary Key from JPA Annotations

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

We use Oracle for our production Database and HSQLDB for our Unit Test Database.  Both environments use Hibernate as the JPA provider.  The following code works properly in production, but throws `SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 23505 - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation` when run under jUnit.  The Entities in question are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUP")
public class TeacherSectionGroup implements TeacherSectionListItem {
  @Id
  @Column(name="TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID",unique=true,nullable=false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID_SEQUENCE")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID_SEQUENCE",sequenceName="TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUP_SQ")
  private Long id;
    .
    .
    .
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
  @JoinTable(name="TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC",joinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID",referencedColumnName="TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID")
  },inverseJoinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name="USERSDCID",referencedColumnName="USERSDCID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="SECTIONSDCID",referencedColumnName="SECTIONSDCID")
  })
  private List<TeacherSection> sections;
    .
    .
    .
```

And the other end of the join:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TT_TEACHERSECTION")
public class TeacherSection implements TeacherSectionListItem {
  @EmbeddedId
  private TeacherSectionPK key;
    .
    .
    .
```

With the Primary Key class:

```
@Embeddable
public class TeacherSectionPK implements Serializable {
  @Column(name="SECTIONSDCID",nullable=false)
  private Long sectionId;

  @Column(name="USERSDCID",nullable=false)
  private Long usersDcid;
    .
    .
    .
```

The (cleaned up) output in the logs contains these hibernate statements that are being issued:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 13820, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 13821, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 13957, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 13958, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 14234, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTION (DISPLAYNAME, POSITION, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (<null>, <null>, 14235, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUP (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, DISPLAYNAME, EXPRESSION, ISMODIFIED, NAME, POSITION, USERSDCID) values (default, <null>, 'Course(91642)', false, 'AP Chemistry', 0, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUP (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, DISPLAYNAME, EXPRESSION, ISMODIFIED, NAME, POSITION, USERSDCID) values (default, <null>, 'Course(723)', false, 'Gen Chemistry', 1, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUP (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, DISPLAYNAME, EXPRESSION, ISMODIFIED, NAME, POSITION, USERSDCID) values (default, <null>, 'Expression(3(A-B))', false, '3(A-B)', 2, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (1, 13820, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (1, 13821, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (2, 13957, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (2, 13958, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (2, 14234, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (2, 14235, 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC (TEACHERSECTIONGROUPID, SECTIONSDCID, USERSDCID) values (3, 13957, 1)
WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 23505
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_CT_10323 table: TT_TEACHERSECTIONGROUPASSOC
```

It appears that HSQLDB is only using the Inverse Join Columns as the Primary Key for the JoinTable instead of all of the columns, as would make sense (and as I've seen documented around the inter-tubes)

Is there a mechanism that I'm missing to specify to HSQLDB which fields should be included in the Primary Key?  Since this code actually works correctly in Oracle (i.e. production), I'm loath to rewrite it just to satisfy a unit test so I'm hoping there's an answer that will work equally well in either environment.  Thanks.

Comment: I assume the difference is that you are using JPA to create your tables on HSQL but the schema already exists on Oracle.  If so, have you tried specifying your relationship as a ManyToMany instead of OneToMany.  There isn't much of a difference between the two when you have specified a join table already, but I believe Hibernate handles the DDL gen differently

Comment: Have you tried to change the `@GeneratedValue` strategy from   `GenerationType.AUTO` to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`? As far I know, the `SEQUENCE` strategy makes use of generator and sequence configuration. And you doesn't need to make `@Column` of `@Id` `required` and `nullable=false` as it already implicitly is.

Comment: @chris, Changing to ManyToMany did the trick.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the correct one.